# Azure App Service failed to start with custom container (trying to configure SSH connection)

Tags: docker

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#connect-to-the-container-using-ssh) from Microsoft to connect to my App Service (running on a custom container) using SSH.

The base image I'm using is [tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx/)

And here's my docker file

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /nodebuild
ADD frontend /nodebuild
ADD .env /nodebuild
RUN export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && npm install && npm audit fix && npm run build


FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:latest

ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app

COPY --from=0 /nodebuild/build /app/frontend/build


RUN export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && python3 manage.py makemigrations -noinput && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN rm .env

# THE BELOW IS FOR SETTING UP SSH
# ----------------------------------
ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
    && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd 

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh
EXPOSE 8000 2222
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
```

Notice the last line of the Dockerfile. It uses `ENTRYPOINT` to set the startup command.

Content of the `init.sh` file is as below (just to start the SSH service).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Starting SSH ..."
service ssh start
```

Now the strange thing is that if I remove the last line (`ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]`) then everything works fine. But if it's there, the app failed to start and the app logs say something like

```
Container abc_xy_0_57397aae didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Comment: What about `set -e`? Do you have container logging enabled?

Comment: I'm actually not so sure about that. What does `set -e` do exactly? Thanks!

Comment: `set` is a [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) that allows you to change the values of shell options and set the positional parameters. Using `-e` could potentially exit upon a non-zero status. Try commenting it out and run again? If you run into errors, please post the container logs.

Comment: sure, thanks! let me do that and get back to you. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure, Python or Linux-specific APIs, adjusted tags accordingly. You could have found that yourself while extracting a [mcve] which you could have executed locally. That said, you usually don't need SSH to get a shell (or another program) executed inside a running container. Docker itself brings that infrastructure (see `docker exec`), though depending on Azure it might actually be easier to get SSH to run than it is to get this "raw" Docker function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entrypoint is equivalent to the init process (PID 1) of a traditional Unix system. If that process terminates, your computer shuts down or reboots. Your bash script starts `sshd` and then terminates. You need to find out what the entrypoint was and call that to preserve the previous behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, you are absolutely right. In the base image, there was another ENTRYPOINT to start the app. What I did was to call this ENTRYPOINT before that one, and everything works now.